# Spring Data JPA ONLY FOR PROFESSIONALS

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

My goal is to create multiple entities (Subbox) from a single entity (Box), just like
[Matryoshka dolls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqomX.jpg).
To abstract what we are addressing here, consider the following scenario:

First we have an entity "Box":

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name="box")
public class Box {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idbox", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int idbox;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private BigDecimal size;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Subbox> subbox;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Content> content;
}
```

and another entity Subbox:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name="subbox")
public class Subbox {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "idsubbox", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int idsubbox;

    @Column(name = "brand")
    private String brand;

    @Column(name = "size")
    private BigDecimal size;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private Box box;

    @OneToMany
    private Set<Content> content;
}
```

If we query from Subbox, we should get something similar to that:

```
+----------+-------+------+-------------------+-----------+
| idsubbox | brand | size | content_idcontent | box_idbox |
+----------+-------+------+-------------------+-----------+
  1          Abcd    5.0     1                  13
  2          Abcd    5.0     1                  13
  3          Abcd    5.0     1                  13
```

So we have 3 different subboxes(1, 2, 3) of the same box(13). The problem is that with the configuration above it's not possible to keep creating subboxes inside a subbox, we would have to create a Subsubbox entity, Subsubsubbox and so on.

The question is, how can I create a Box inside a Box infinitely without having to create N entities?
An inner box (the box inside a top box) should have the very same properties from the top box, but its values could differ, just like the dolls have different sizes.

Comment: Just use a single entity, box, with a `parent_box_id` column which can be null for a top level box. That's my amateur's (well, ex-professional) opinion, anyway.

Comment: And if you google "jpa tree" there are many tutorials on how to do this.

Comment: Awesome, I'll take a look on that! Btw, don't mind the post's title, it is just meant to attract ppl attention since it have got like 20 views from the day I posted it (48h+ ago). It seems it worked out well kek